# When do finite linear orders have the same theory in MSO?

Tags: order-theory, model-theory, first-order-logic

Let $\mathfrak A$ and $\mathfrak B$ be finite linears orders and $m<\omega$. Then we have
$$\mathfrak A \equiv^m_{FO}\mathfrak B \quad\text{iff}\quad |A|=|B| \,\, \text{or}\,\, |A|,|B|\ge 2^m-1.$$

My question: **Is there a similar result for monadic second order logic?**

So I'm looking for a result like:
$$\mathfrak A \equiv^m_{MSO}\mathfrak B \quad\text{iff}\quad ?$$

My thoughts concerning this question:

There are only finitely many theories of bounded quantifier rank in MSO. So although MSO has a stronger expressive power than FO there are different finite linear orders which are not distinguishable via MSO given a certain quantifier rank. Nevertheless, for large quantifier ranks $m<\omega$ there won't be a $n<\omega$, such that all orders with at least $n$ elements have the same theory. This is because there is a MSO formular $\varphi$ which is true iff the order has even cardinality.

$$\varphi:= \exists X \forall x [(\min(x)\rightarrow Xx) \land (\max(x)\rightarrow \lnot Xx) \land \forall y (\text{succ}(x,y)\rightarrow (Xx\leftrightarrow \lnot Xy)) ]$$
with

$$\min(x):= \forall y \, x\le y$$
$$\max(x):= \forall y \, y\le x$$
$$\text{succ}(x,y):= \forall z [(x\le z \land z\le y)\rightarrow (x=z \lor y=z)]$$

This $\varphi$ has quantifier rank 4, so for $m\ge 4$ there won't be a $n<\omega$, such that all finite orders $\mathfrak A$ with at least $n$ elements have the same theory $\text{Th}_{MSO}^m(\mathfrak A)$. In particular we see that all orders of the same theroy are of the same parity.

Comment: I know little of this kind of logic (bounded quantifier rank), but I suppose the answer is strongly dependent on the signature you're working in. You should make it clear what it is, in particular, do you treat maximum and successor as shorthand for definable predicates?

Comment: That said, my (un)informed guess would be that for sufficiently large linear orders, this kind of equivalence depends on the residues modulo $p$ -- for small enough $p$ -- of the size.

Comment: The signature for orders is $\{\le\}$. Yeah, max, min and succ are shorthands to make the formular $\varphi$ more readable. I showed below the definition of $\varphi$ how max, min and succ are defined.

Comment: With bounded quantifier rank I mean that we first fix $m<\omega$ and then consider $\text{Th}_{\text{MSO}}^m(\mathfrak A):=\{\varphi\in \text{MSO}[\le] \mid \mathfrak A \vDash \varphi \text{ and qr}(\varphi)\le m  \}$.

Comment: I do understand what it means and I did know the definition, I'm just not familiar with it (or second order logic for that matter).

Comment: **Monadic** second order logic means that you only have unary second order variables. But maybe you also knew that already ;)

Comment: Hint: Combine the following two facts to answer your question 1) finite structures have the same first-order theory iff they are isomorphic, 2) the monadic second order language is more expressive than the first-order one.

Comment: @boumol You forgot the quantifier rank. Of course all those structures have the same FO/MSO theory iff they are isomorphic iff they have the same number of elements. But here we don't consider the full theory but only the theory restricted to a certain quantifier rank.